# Counting number of frames on stack

Tags: c, assembly, callstack

To start off, I need to write a assembly (Intel IA-32) function that returns the contents of the caller's frame pointer. I don't think I'm doing it correctly, but what I came up with was

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl %eax, 4(ebp)
leave
ret
```

However, I'm supposed to use that in a c function to count the number of frames on the stack, and I'm really not sure at all how that is supposed to work. Am I supposed to jump to the value in the old ebp, and then call the function again? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not required to jump anywhere, but once you have copied the frame pointer to a local variable, you can treat it as a linked list.

```
 int mymagicfunction(int a, int b){

     int *c = asm_copy_ebp();
     int *d = c;
     while ( it_makes_sense ) {
           c=*c;
           dump_memory_between(c,d);
           d=c;
     }
```

Perhaps it makes sense only when the distance between c and d is small.

Comment: or maybe the new c is in c[-1] or c[1]... You'll figure it out by dumping memory around the pointer and comparing the contents... I'm off for some more red wine.

Comment: It usually makes sense until it reaches NULL. At least on Linux/glibc, but it's probably required by ELF.

Comment: @ninjalj: that's a sure one.

Comment: This ended up being very close to the correct answer. The way I ended up doing it was using just a single int* c  and while(c != 0) then c = *c;  The linked list concept was the main part of my misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. I would have still used the c->d (or d->c) approach to track how many bytes to print.